# Trying to make a CHttpFile::SendRequest, device hangs

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm trying to fetch contents of an URL on a WM 6.5 not so uber gizmo, using VC++ 2008

```
CString http_request(CString params){

CInternetSession session(_T("My Session")); // add device identifier here?
CHttpConnection* pServer = NULL;
CHttpFile* pFile = NULL;
CString szHeaders( _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;Accept: text/xml, text/plain, text/html, text/htm\r\nHost: www.mydomain.com\r\n\r\n"));
CString strObject(""); 
CString out;
DWORD dwRet;

char *szBuff = new char[1023];

try
{

    CString strServerName("www.mydomain.com");
   INTERNET_PORT nPort(80);

   pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(strServerName, nPort);
   pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, strObject);
   pFile->AddRequestHeaders(szHeaders);
   pFile->SendRequest(LPCTSTR(params),params.GetLength());
   pFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet);

   if (dwRet == HTTP_STATUS_OK)
   {
       UINT nRead = pFile->Read(szBuff, 1023);
       while (nRead > 0)
       {
           //read file...
           out = CString(szBuff);
       }
   }
   delete pFile;
   delete pServer;
}
catch (CInternetException* pEx)
{
   //catch errors from WinInet
out = CString("Something went wrong.");
}
session.Close();

return out;

}
```

I do see the request coming in but the URI does not get passed, the server throws a 500 or 404 because of this.

I've tried passing params as "GET /blah.txt HTTP/1.0" and also "/blah.txt", no luck, would like to keep testing various input parameters but the device hangs for some reason...

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

TIA

**Later edit: Solution:**

Here's how I got it to work, full code snippet in case anyone wants a copy paste solution (yeah these come in handy)

```
CString http_request(CString server, CString uri){

CInternetSession session(_T("My Session")); // add device identifier here? IMEI ftw
CHttpConnection* pServer = NULL;
CHttpFile* pFile = NULL;
CString szHeaders( _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;Accept: text/xml, text/plain, text/html, text/htm\r\nHost: www.domain.com\r\n\r\n")); // maybe pass as param?
CString strObject(uri); 
CString out;
DWORD dwRet;
CString params;

char *szBuff = new char[1023];

try
{

    CString strServerName(server);
   INTERNET_PORT nPort(80);

   pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(strServerName, nPort);
   pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, strObject);
   pFile->AddRequestHeaders(szHeaders);

   pFile->SendRequest(szHeaders, szHeaders.GetLength(),&params, params.GetLength());
   pFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet);

   if (dwRet == HTTP_STATUS_OK)
   {
       UINT nRead = pFile->Read(szBuff, 1023);
       //while (nRead > 0)
       //{
           //read, for more data you might want to uncomment the while and append to a var. I only needed a few bytes actually.

           out = CString(szBuff);
       //}
   } else {
        out = CString("Communication error!");
   }
   delete pFile;
   delete pServer;
}
catch (CInternetException* pEx)
{
    //catch errors from WinInet

    out = CString("Network error!"); // stupid a$$ cpp the code to handle this would be longer than my ****
}
session.Close();
pServer->Close();

return out;

}
```

Comment: your strObject is empty. Shouldn't this be where you put "blah.txt"? Please add to your question what parameters your passing to this function.

Comment: That did it! had to mess with the parameters in some weird unusual ways (originally tried passing the CString with no luck). This is all strange to me, I come from a Linux background. Thank you again very much for your comment! Maybe you can post it as answer and I'll update the question now with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your strObject is empty. Shouldn't this be where you put "blah.txt"?

also, you should delete[] szBuf;

and you're calling pServer->Close() after you've deleted pServer which will probably cause your app to except.